# WebLogic JMS and C#

Tags: c#, jms, weblogic

I am a amateur with WebLogic and JMS and hopefully someone can help with my "Stupid Question"

I would like to ask in regards to interfacing a C# client application with a WebLogic Server using JMS

1. Does the C# client application need to have a WebLogic client in order to interact using JMS with WebLogic Server, or can the C# client application just use the JMS API to use JMS to interact with WebLogic Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13746/develop.htm).
This should explain you how to use the WebLogic JMS .NET API.

Comment: as long as you include the referenced library, your code will run.  The standard Java API is obviously not available.

Comment: Do i need to have a WebLogic JMS .NET Client installed in order to interface with a WebLogic Server, or can i just use the JMS .NET Library or will i need both?